# Delete sqlite database file in .net environment

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm doing some integration tests of a software which uses SQLite.

The software needs to use a database file to prevent data being lost. After each of the tests, I want to delete the database file to leave everything as it was at the beginning.

The problem is  that when I Try to delete the file It throws an exception which says "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '*****' because it is being used by another process". Before trying to delete the file, I'm closing and disposing of the connection like this:

```
if(_connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Close();
_connection.Dispose();
```

To delete the file I am using the instruction: `File.Delete(_databaseFilePath);`
What am I doing wrong?, Do I miss something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this post is addressing the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532729/sqlite-keeps-the-database-locked-even-after-the-connection-is-closed

Comment: Thanks the post was helpful. At the end, the solution was to call GC.Collect() and sleep the Thread for some milliseconds.