# SQLite file locked after closing

Tags: powershell, sqlite

Aware of [System.Data.SQLite Close() not releasing database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511901/system-data-sqlite-close-not-releasing-database-file) and [SQLite keeps the database locked even after the connection is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532729/sqlite-keeps-the-database-locked-even-after-the-connection-is-closed)

I originally tried `Close`, but added `Dispose` and the `GC` functions. No change. File indefinitely held open by PowerShell. Using http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.115.5/sqlite-netFx40-binary-x64-2010-1.0.115.5.zip.

```
function Connect-SQLiteDatabase([ref][Object]$conn){
    try{
        $conn.Value.Open()
    }catch{
        Write-Warning -Message ("Failed to connect: " + $_.Exception.Message)
    }
}

function Disconnect-SQLiteDatabase([ref][Object]$conn, [Switch]$Dispose){
    try{
        $conn.Value.Close()
        if($Dispose){
            $conn.Value.Dispose()
        }

        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }catch{
        Write-Warning -Message ("Failed to disconnect: " + $_.Exception.Message)
    }
}

function Initialize-SQLite(){
    try{
        Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\SQLite\System.Data.SQLite.dll" -ErrorAction Stop
        [void][System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection]
    }catch{
        Write-Error -Message "Could not import SQLite. Ensure the dll is present in .\lib\SQLite\"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, calling close / dispose is what you are supposed to do... While you show your 3 function, you do not give us a reproducible example to see the problem. The issue probably lies in the way you call these 3 functions. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

It seems `SQLiteCommand` was the problem, `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery`. Disposing the object solved it.

```
function Invoke-SQLiteNonQuery([System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand]$sqlCommand, [Switch]$NoDispose){
    $data = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    if(-not $NoDispose){
        $sqlCommand.Dispose()
    }

    return $data
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was searching all around until I found your answer and got my issue fixed up.